# Странности работы chararray

Tags: java, массивы, split

Впервые понадобился chararray и я не совсем понимаю. Если кратко, то есть строка 134, я делаю tochararray и тут для меня начинается магия.

```
String text = "134";
String[] ary = text.split(" ");
```

Если делать так, то все отлично:

```
System.out.println(arr[0] + " " + arr[1] + " " + arr[2]);
```

Но если сделать так, то цифры как то странно суммируются и получается 152:

```
System.out.println(arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2]);
```

Обьясните, почему они суммируются, и каким образом получается такое число?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда Вы делаете `System.out.println(arr[0] + " " + arr[1] + " " + arr[2]);`

происходит конкатенация в строку, т.к добавляете `+ " "`

В случае с `System.out.println(arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2]);`

в первую очередь суммируются **ASCII** коды символов (т.к это `Char`), а именно:

```
1 - 49
3 - 51
4 - 52
```

Что в сумме дает 49 + 51 + 52 = 152.